# User authentication and login flow with Ember and JSON web tokens

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying to figure out how is best to do authentication and login flow with Ember. I'll also add that this is the first web app I've built so it's all a bit new to me.

I have an Express.js backend with protected endpoints using JWTs (I'm using  Passport, express-jwt and jsonwebtoken for that) and that all works.

On the client-side, I'm using Ember
 Simple Auth with the JWT authenticator. I have the login flow working (I'm using the login-controller-mixin) and correctly see the isAuthenticated flag in the inspector after a successful login.

The thing I'm struggling with is what to do after login: once a user logs in and gets the token, should I make a subsequent call to get the user details, e.g. GET /me, so that I can then have a representative user model client side? These details would then let me transition to the appropriate route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this example in the repo](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/4-authenticated-account.html#L132) for an example of how to add a property to the session that provides access to the current user.

Comment: Thank you @marcoow - I got it working based on your example and by following this related blog post: http://blog.willrax.com/fetching-the-current-user-with-simple-auth/

Comment: This is why you shouldn't just link to examples without explanations, the link is now dead (404) and as someone who has just found this question - the entire thing is meaningless to me.